# Integral divisors of $a^n-b^n$ - misinterpretation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am reading [Birkhoff and Vandiver (1904) Integral divisors of $a^n-b^n$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007263) and I am a bit confused.

From Fermat we know that $$x\equiv y \mod \phi(n) \Rightarrow a^x\equiv a^y \mod n$$
or
$$n\equiv 0 \mod (p-1) \Rightarrow m^n\equiv 1 \mod p$$

but on page 2, what I read seems to be something like

*...$ \mathit{m^n\equiv1 \mod p}$. It now follows from the definition of p, that m appertains to n, modulo p, so that $\mathit{p - 1\equiv 0\mod n}$...*

which I interpret (in thoose particular conditions) as
$$ m^n\equiv 1 \mod p\Rightarrow (p-1)\equiv 0 \mod n$$

What am I missing? Because it would mean
$$n\equiv 0 \mod (p-1) \Rightarrow (p-1)\equiv 0 \mod n$$ 
or $n=(p-1)$ which is not the case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary that if $m^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies n \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$. For example, we can take $$2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$
The smallest value $n$ can take, say $d$ is the order of $m$ modulo $p$. Here, we say that $3$ is the order of $2$ modulo $7$. It is not necessary that the order takes the value $p-1$. However, we can see that by definition of minimality of $d$, if $p-1=dq+r$ by division algorithm, then:
$$m^{p-1-dq} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies m^r \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \implies r=0$$
as $0<r<d$ would contradict the minimality of $d$. That is why it follows that $p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$. In the above context, I guess that $n$ was referring to the order.

Comment: Well, $p$ is a primitive divisor of $a^n-b^n$, and $m$ was set as $a\equiv bm \mod p$. Does this implies $n$ is the order of $m$ modulo $p$? (how?). Indeed, if $n$ is the order of $m$ than I can see why $n<p$ (implied by $p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$)

Comment: @user489810 Yes, $n$ will be the order. We will have $(bm)^n \equiv b^n \pmod{p} \implies m^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. As $p$ is a primitive prime divisor, $n$ must take the minimum possible value. This is the order of $m$ modulo $p$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I still think that "...It now follows from the definition of p, that m appertains to n, modulo p, so that ..." was a bit foggy though